# How to display all the biggest strings in a stack with typescript

Tags: typescript, stack, maxlength

I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to make a function that fetches and returns the length of the biggest string in the stack. I think I got the structure right but I'm missing something on the way things are written here. Since the number I get back is always 0 as if it doesnt go through the loop.

Can someone help?

```
class ConstantTimeStack {
  public string: any[] | null;

  constructor() {
    this.string = null;
  }

  //push method
  public push(item: string): void {
    if (!this.string) {
      this.string = [item];
    } else {
      this.string.push(item);
    }
  }

  //max length method
  public maxLength(): number {
    let stackLength = ConstantTimeStack.length;
    let temp = 0;
    let newSize = 0;
    let maxSize = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < stackLength; ++i) {
      temp = ConstantTimeStack[i].length;
      if (temp >= newSize) {
        temp = newSize;
      } else {
        newSize = maxSize;
      }
    }
    return maxSize;
  }
}

let stack = new ConstantTimeStack();
stack.push("Iron");
stack.push("Man");
stack.push("is");
stack.push("the");
stack.push("man");
console.log(stack.maxLength());
```

Comment: I have rearranged variables a bit (you don't need 3 variables to find max, 2 is enough -- current value and max value), and also fixed references to `this.string` (it was like `ConstantTimeStack.something`, which is a static field reference, not a normal field).

Comment: thanks but where do i go to access that code you edited?

Comment: My bad, the link is too huge for a comment. And can't post bit.ly link, that service seems to be banned. Let me post full answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed code (and [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7CAXMiUBUCWBbApgMprADW0A3gFDTQAOArgEYjbDSoBO2iA5gFzR0ATwDaAXWgAfaIgYgQAbio1owJFwbAU8TgAoAlJVW0UAC2wQAdFx69oAXlnylqgL4raAei+MIZ6AJzeAATVUYWNnoGfz1sFHxcQVs+A0EAN3hsEONaWmwAM2g9AEJzSxsUblTcvNMLaxT7J1F4xPFlOrdofBAIfFq68saquys-MziE3ANOvI9aD1UfXDAAD2gQfD5zQPxgsNoI1nZVtYAZbd5zQ0E5XCZ8TkHN-Y4SUkudgKdhyureCUrFtvnNaFsULJ8AB3QjYABeAycAAYwa9IWc4YjHNBUSZoAVdMUIdBsDjUaToAAed5gMhfa5mRTQADULOwRmodVoiBhWKR0D+TRKrXEwKu5jR+SKel5sIRAwAfE5MQrOfi6qrsU45fypdAFvN8Zx9gxOIhAus9e4qEsSag6eQdTC4Bo0BgcARiI7DMoHWRxjFJgAiACSnCQwdmVH9pEDsWDAFl0FG-R94yHLKmY+mJnpg+Z8NnYxn86tENn1Mh4FtgfBeHoS2cGTcDLMgA)):

```js
class ConstantTimeStack {
  public string: any[] | null;

  constructor() {
    this.string = null;
  }

  //push method
  public push(item: string): void {
    if (!this.string) {
      this.string = [item];
    } else {
      this.string.push(item);
    }
  }

  //max length method
  public maxLength(): number {
    let stackLength = this.string!.length;
    let newSize = 0;
    let maxSize = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < stackLength; ++i) {
      newSize = this.string![i].length;
      if (newSize >= maxSize) {
        maxSize = newSize;
      }
    }
    return maxSize;
  }
}

let stack = new ConstantTimeStack();
stack.push("Iron");
stack.push("Man");
stack.push("is");
stack.push("the");
stack.push("man");
console.log(stack.maxLength());
```

I have rearranged variables a bit (you don't need 3 variables to find max, 2 is enough -- current value and max value), and also fixed references to this.string (it was like ConstantTimeStack.something, which is a static field reference, not a normal field).